# any way of password masking in AWS lex bot

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-lex

Is there any way to set data type of the input(in chabox) in amazon lex to password datatype or any way to mask the password shared in the AWS lex Chatbot?

Answer (score 0):

Amazon Lex is entirely separate from the user interface used to pass messages to Lex.

So any configuration dealing with the chatbox, will need to be done within your specific channel's chat display settings. And that will differ between channels (Facebook Messenger, SMS, Skype, etc.).

If you are using the Lex Test Chat, be aware that it has its own unique formatting, built entirely separate from Lex, so don't confuse those two. Lex only deals with receiving messages, parsing the language, and delivering appropriate responses. How the incoming messages and outgoing responses are displayed is entirely controlled by the channel.

Just to give you an example of how something like this can be done using Facebook Messenger.
You can use [Facebook Webview](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webview/) to open an html form inside the facebook chat that uses the password input:
 `<input type="password"...>`